# Looking for a better way to initiate cron job

Tags: plugin-development, wp-cron

Is there any other good way to initiate an hourly cron job other than using `register_activation_hook` within a plugin?

As looks like it will not be useful for websites that have already installed and activated that plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if the event is scheduled, and if not, schedule it:

```
add_action(
    'init',
    function () {
        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'my_scheduled_event' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_scheduled_event' );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My concern with this approach is performance cost. As call to `wp_next_scheduled` results in a DB request and doing that on the `init` hook seems expensive.

Comment: It doesn't make a DB request. It consults an [autoloaded option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_get_cron_array/), so no additional performance hit.

Comment: Right, Thanks for the clarification.